# How to convert TimeStamp to appropriate Date format?

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I have the `TimeStamp` and I need to convert it to `Data` type object that should match this pattern - "2016-11-16T18:42:33.049Z". How can I do that?

Comment: What is "the `TimeStamp`"? Is it a `java.sql.Timestamp`, or something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Date d = new Date((long)timestamp*1000);
```

will create a `Date` instance. Displaying it later is another thing.

I think it's what you want:

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");
System.out.println(f.format(date));
```

Test:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Date d = new Date((long)1481723817*1000);
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");
        System.out.println(f.format(d));
    }
}

>>2016-12-14T14:56:57.056Z
```

Comment: I need date to perfectly match the pattern cause I'm using it for query to dynamoDB... Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: You should keep timestamp in DynamoDB. Date is Date and don't worry abut the display format.

Comment: @neckobik try the above code. I looks like it works.

Comment: actually I need it to make condition for querying secondary index in aws dynamoDB. that is why i need exact same representation as i mentioned before. Case query will compare everything as Strings (Date attribute in Dynamo db is a String value). But ty for your answer any ways. I will test it now.

Comment: I think you intended your format to be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` ending in milliseconds: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

Convert like this.

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

you can also use the data object in the manner u want.