# How to convert timestamp field from firestore to Date in android?

Tags: java, android, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a field createAt (timestamp) in a document. When I get it from firestore, I receive below constructor. How can I convert it to Date in Java?

D/TEST: Timestamp field: Timestamp(seconds=1621098000, nanoseconds=0)

here is my code

```
fStore.collection("Bill").whereEqualTo("userID", userID).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> billArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            billArrayList.add(document.getData());
                            String id = document.getId();
                            Integer addressID = Integer.parseInt(billArrayList.get(0).get("addressID").toString());
                            //Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) billArrayList.get(0).get("createAt");
                            Log.d("TEST", "Timestamp field: " + billArrayList.get(0).get("createAt"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }});
```

I have tried convert this timestamp to long but it not work

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144296/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-appropriate-date-format/41144310

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash thanks for your help.
I just find solution for my problem. It make me so crazy.
`Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) billArrayList.get(0).get("createAt");
Date createAt = ts.toDate();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find the solution for my problem

```
Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) billArrayList.get(0).get("createAt");
Date createAt = ts.toDate();
```